# MaxDrillthroughRecords on IOLEDBConnection resets after changing Connection

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I'm working with an `IOLEDBConnection` object, and changing the `MaxDrillthoughRecords` field works as expected. However, I also need to change the `Connection` field of the `IOLEDBConnection` and when I do this then the `MaxDrillthroughRecords` field gets set to 1000. I don't want this to happen.

```
IOLEDBConnection oleConnection = connection.OLEDBConnection;
try
{
    this.SetMaxDrillthroughRecords();
    var a = oleConnection.MaxDrillthroughRecords; // MaxDrillthroughRecords is 5 here.
    oleConnection.Connection = new object[] { connection.ConnectionString };
    a = oleConnection.MaxDrillthroughRecords; // MaxDrillthroughRecords is 1000 here.
}
finally { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oleConnection); }
```

I tried to use Reflector to view the code in the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` assembly but was strangely unable to locate the interface. Is there some subtle behavior I'm missing here? Thanks for any help.